# iMessage not Sending, New Text Icon not Disappearing, Conversations Deleted

Tags: iphone, messages

I'm having some really strange issues all of a sudden on my iPhone6 after updating to iOS 8.4.1.  It seems to only occur with one contact, who has an iPhone5 also with iOS 8.4.1.  Some problems are:

1. iMessages won't send, and immediately show 'Not Delivered'.  Sending as an SMS sometimes works.
2. The new text message icons, both the red "1" on the app icon and the blue dot in the app next to the contact's name, don't disappear when I open our conversation.  Moreover, it's there even when no new messages are visible.
3. Our conversations get deleted every time I restart my phone.  In fact, last time I restarted my phone, two separate conversations were shown with this same contact.  I attempted to send three iMessages, and in one conversation they each say 'not delivered' and in the second converation, only the second iMessage attempt is visible, and is still showing "sending" at the top, with the progess bar stuck at about 90%.

Apple support was no help.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try with disabling and the reenabling iMessage in Settings -> Messages -> iMessage. Please note that doing this will require your phone to send a SMS to Apple, in some countries this will be sent to an another country.

Comment: @Dempa I've tried all of these quick fixes, including all the fixes suggested by Apple Care.  Any other thoughts?